# Python: 5 missing positional arguments

Tags: python, function, module

The inside of the function works as desired, but I can't figure how to get the positional arguments. The function has all of those pieces called for?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ironmomo/Documents/testingspirograph/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    drawCirclePattern()
TypeError: drawCirclePattern() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'centerX', 'centerY', 'offset', 'radius', and 'count'
```

Code:

```
centerX = eval(input("Center x: "))
centerY = eval(input("Center y: "))
offset = eval(input("Offset: "))
count = eval(input("Count: "))
radius = eval(input("Radius: "))

def drawCirclePattern(centerX, centerY, offset, radius, count):
   import turtle
   turtle.goto(centerX, centerY)
   turtle.seth(0)
   countOG = count
   while count > 0:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.fd(offset)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.circle(radius)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(centerX, centerY)
        turtle.right((countOG / 2) - 180)
        count -= 1

drawCirclePattern()
```

Comment: Please, format your code (adding 4 spaces before every line would be enough)

Comment: Please format your code - [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Replace `eval` with `int` or `float`, depending on what kind of input you expect. `eval`=`evil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling drawCirclePattern() without parameters, but there should be 5.

For examle: `drawCirclePattern(100, 200, 50, 100, 10)`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to stipulate I was looking for inputs outside of the function itself.

Comment: The code inside the function has no knowledge of what is outside of the function, you need to pass the arguments as is stated in this answer in order for the function to be aware of those values.